# Using a trigger/function with a constraint

Tags: oracle, database-trigger, stored-functions, check-constraints

I know there will be many who will say that such question has been posted before and i should check. However, i did and i am unable to relate, and that is why i am posting something new.

I currently have the tables below:

```
   create table patient
    (
    patientno varchar2(10) primary key,
    firstname varchar2(50) not null,
    lastname varchar2(50) not null,
    address varchar2(1000) not null,
    registereddate date not null,
    waitinglistdate date,
    expectedstay number(2),
    datewarded date,
    expectedleave date,
    dateleft date
    )

create table ward
(
    wardno number(4) primary key,
    wardname varchar2(50) not null,
    location varchar2(50) not null,
    numberofbed number(2) not null,
);

create table bed
(
    bedno number(3) not null,
    patientno varchar2(10) not null,
    wardno number(4) not null,
    bed_occupieddate date not null,
    dateleft date,
    constraint bed_pk key primary key (bedno, bed_occupieddate),
    constraint bedwardnoFK foreign key (wardno) references ward(wardno),
    constraint patientbedFK foreign key (patientno) references patient(patientno)
);
```

I need to tackle the problem of:
**A patient can only be warded into the ward if that are beds available in the ward**

The NumberOfBed in WARD table is the total number of beds in the ward. E.g., there are 20 beds in Ward A.

So i believe this is the code that i need somewhere in the trigger or function: **IF (ward.numberofbed - [count(bed.wardno) where bed.dateleft IS NOT NULL]) != 0**

If this would be a function, how would i be able to add in the ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT statement for BED table?
So basically if all beds in the ward is occupied (dateleft=NULL), new patients cannot be inserted into the BED table.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are no cross table check constraints(**[assertions](https://community.oracle.com/ideas/13028)**). You could try to emulate such check with function but the performance will suffer. You could use different approach: open transaction, check if there are free beds, if yes insert value and commit.

Comment: I've seen your previous threads on this.  I believe your entire approach of tracking against 'number of beds' is flawed.  Your 'beds' table has a list of individual beds in each ward.  If a given bed has a null value for patientno, then the bed is available.   Easy-peasy.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with relying on a trigger to retroactively check whether a bed is free is that Oracle has READ COMMIT isolation level. So two users in parallel sessions can allocate the last bed in a ward to two different people. This is a bad idea, even without the spectre of COVID-19.

I think your data model is slightly wrong. BED ought to be a fixed table, as a child of WARD. Then you should have a table BED_OCCUPANCY which is an intersection between BED and PATIENT. You track `bed_occupieddate` and `dateleft` on BED_OCCUPANCY not BED.

The advantage of this model is that the number of BED records remains fixed for each WARD, so you can easily tell which beds are currently occupied. It also gives you a record which **can be locked**. Such optimistic locking means that when a user finds BED #12 in WARD #1 is empty they can allocate a patient to that bed knowing that a colleague is not simultaneously allocating a different patient to the same bed in a different session.

With this approach your application would look something like this:

```
create or replace procedure allocate_patient_to_bed
  (p_patient_id in  patient.patient_id%type
   ,p_ward_no   out ward.ward_no%type
   ,p_bed_no    out ned.bed_no%type) 
is
  cursor get_bed is
    select bed.ward_no
           ,bed.bed_no
    from bed
    where bed.bed_no not in (
      select bed_occupancy.bed_no
      from bed_occupancy 
      where bed_occupancy.dateleft is null)
    for update;
  r_bed get_bed%rowtype;

begin

  open get_bed;

  fetch get_bed into r_bed;

  if get_bed%not_found then
    close get_bed;
    raise_application_error(-20999, 'No beds available!');
  end if;

  insert into bed_occupancy (bed_occupancy_id, patient_id, bed_no, bed_occupieddate)
  values (bed_occupancy_seq.nextval, p_patient_id, r_bed.bed_no, sysdate);

  commit;

  close get_bed;

  p_ward_no := r_bed.ward_no;
  p_bed_no  := r_bed.bed_no;

end allocate_patient_to_bed;
```